# Firebase Functions Test fails to wrap v2 function

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, testing, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 Firebase functions, `hello` in v1 and `hello2` in v2

```typescript
import { https } from "firebase-functions";
import { onCall } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";

export const hello = https.onCall((request) => {
  return `Hello ${request.data.text}`;
});

export const hello2 = onCall((request) => {
  return `Hello ${request.data.text}`;
});
```

`hello` can be wrapped with `firebase-functions-test` SDK with no issue, but `hello2` throws an error. Is `firebase-functions-test` supports only v1 but not v2? How can I do this for v2 functions?

```typescript
import { hello, hello2 } from ".";
import { expect } from "chai";
import { wrap } from "firebase-functions-test/lib/main";

describe("hello function", () => {
  it("returns expected output", async () => {
    // Create a test request object.
    const request = {
      body: {
        text: "World",
      },
    };

    const wrapped = wrap(hello);
    // The following line fails with No overload matches this call.
    const wrapped2 = wrap(hello2);

    const response = await wrapped(request);
    // The following line fails with Argument of type '{ body: { text: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CallableRequest<any>'.
    const response2 = await wrapped2(request);

    expect(response).equal("Hello World");
    expect(response2).equal("Hello World");
  });
});
```

Comment: Based on [`firebase/firebase-functions-test` Issue #163](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/163), at the time of writing v2 `onCall` functions are not yet supported. I recommend going and upvoting the relevant comments in that thread (i.e. don't comment "me too").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering as a Community Wiki, so that it may help others too.

As @samthecodingman mentioned in the comment, According to [`firebase/firebase-functions-test Issue #163`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/163), as of now `v2 onCall` functions are not yet supported.